# building a overlay fullscreen navbar in vue.js, by toggle navbar height from 0% to 100%

Tags: vuejs2, navbar, overlay, fullscreen, conditional-rendering

Trying to implement the overlay fullscreen menu with Vue.js,  html/css/js is [this solution]https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay2

But stuck with how to toggle div height from 0% to 100%. I did create 2 classes,

- 'navbar'
- 'navbar_open'

but I am not sure how to toggle between them in Vue. I could see that once @click triggered, the *class="navbar navbar_open"*

```html
<div id="myNav" class="navbar navbar_open">
  <div class="closebtn">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-content">
  <a>Home</a><a>Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

below is the App.vue file,

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Banner/Header -->
    <!-- Hamburger -->
    <div id="myNav" class="navbar" :class="{ navbar_open: showNavbar }">
      <div class="closebtn" v-on:click="showNavbar = !showNavbar">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-content">
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="openbtn">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" v-on:click="showNavbar = !showNavbar"></i>
    </div>

    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showNavbar: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleNavbar() {
      this.showNavbar = !showNavbar;
    },
    setHeightValue(showNavbar) {
      const heightValue = this.showNavbar ? '100%' : '0%';
      return heightValue;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.setHeightValue();
  }
};
</script>

<style>
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css');

.navbar_open {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #2b4c72;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #2b4c72;
}

.navbar-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.navbar a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.navbar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .navbar {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .navbar a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .navbar .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have unused method `toggleNavbar`. You call `setHeightValue` only when your component is created and then never again (I think you can remove this method). This menu is not 100% height probably because you embedded this component in another container (`<div id="app:...`) which has smaller height so `height: 100%` will be 100% height of parent container. Instead of 100% you can use **`100vh`** (vh - is a viewport unit and it will always take 100% viewport height [if 50vh then 50% of total viewport height]). You should also apply only `navbar_open` but now you are applying bot classes if your navbar is open: `navabar navbar_open` so you should add this classes conditionally:

```js
:class="{ 'navbar_open': showNavbar, 'navbar': !showNavbar }"
```

You have also Two different buttons responsible for two different actions:

- **`closebtn`** -> close navigation
- **`openbtn`** -> open navigation

So you should create two different methods `openNavigation` `closeNavigation`

```html
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Banner/Header -->
    <!-- Hamburger -->
    <div id="myNav" :class="{ 'navbar_open': showNavbar, 'navbar': !showNavbar }">
      <div class="closebtn" @click="closeNavigation">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-content">
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="openbtn">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" @click="showNavigation"></i>
    </div>

    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showNavbar: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openNavigation() {
      this.showNavbar = true;
    },
    closeNaviagation() {
      this.showNavbar = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style>
 ...
.navbar_open {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; // <--- 100vh instead of 100%
  position: fixed;
  ...
</style>
```

Comment: no difference with setting height: 100vh or 100%. I did quick test with devtool (manually modify), same result. the problem is both classes of 'navbar' and 'nabbar_open' showed up at the same time. not one or another.

Comment: @KimchiRice try this now

Comment: @Krzsztof another way, by keepping previous binding but changing CSS style sequence, put .navbar in the front of .navbar_open.